# Output numbers in ascending order (if - else) java

Tags: java, if-statement

Tell me what is missing? Two values are sorted correctly, but the average is not :(

```
package com.Star;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 89;
        int b = 96;
        int c = 88;

        if (a < b & a < c)
            System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);

        if (b < c & b < a)
            System.out.println(b + " " + c + " " + a);

        if (c < a & c < b)
            System.out.println(c + " " + b + " " + a);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the max and min, you can always get the average as `a + b + c - max - min`.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to print them in order, each `if` is only determining the first value.  For example, if first `if` is true, `a` is first, since `a` is less than both `b` and `c`.  But it does not check whether `b < c` or `b > c`.

Comment: `if (a < b & a < c)` This only gets the minimum in the right place, assuming that there is one number smaller than both of the others. You'd want `a <= b && b <= c` to do it correctly.

Comment: The easiest way would be to put these values into a list, and then use Collections.sort

Comment: Additionally, you're missing the other cases (there are 6 permutations of 3 numbers).

Comment: But if I add more lines of "if" it appears the new line in the console

Answer (score 0):

This is not a right way to do this, but if you replace & with && you can get a partially correct code, since you have to check 6    permutation for 3 elements (nPr). Use Array and apply sorting method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 89;
        int b = 96;
        int c = 88;

        if (a < b && b < c)
            System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
        else if (a < c && c < b)
            System.out.println(a + " " + c + " " + b);
        else if (b < a && a < c)
            System.out.println(b + " " + a + " " + c);
        else if (b < c && c < a)
            System.out.println(b + " " + c + " " + a);
        else if (c < a && a < b)
            System.out.println(c + " " + a + " " + b);
        else if (c < b && b < a)
            System.out.println(c + " " + b + " " + a);

        }
```

Comment: if you change the number in "b" below, it does not work :( Example number 80

Comment: I made a mistake. You can try now

Comment: in this case there is no *logical* difference in using `&` or `&&` (second is just the short-circuiting alternative of first) - that is not the problem of the code posted in the question! BTW better use `<=` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

What abute using an array and sorting function?

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    int a = 89;
    int b = 96;
    int c = 88;

    int[] arr = { a, b, c };
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.format("%d %d %d\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
}
```